# Why is does my game code appear as a black screen on pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new at coding and on stack exchange. I have been trying to get this code to run a game based off a tutorial and it keeps appearing as a black screen. I think it probably has something to do with spacing? Can anyone help me? I am sure this code can also be simplified, so any advice on that would be appreciated as well.

```
import pygame
import random
    from pygame.locals import (
        RLEACCEL,
        K_UP,
        K_DOWN,
        K_LEFT,
        K_RIGHT,
        K_ESCAPE,
        KEYDOWN,
        QUIT,
    )
    
    pygame.init()
    
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    
    running = True
    
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
    
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
    
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
    
    surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
    rect = surf.get_rect()
    
    screen.blit(surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    surf_center = (
        (SCREEN_WIDTH-surf.get_width())/2,
        (SCREEN_HEIGHT-surf.get_height())/2
    )
    
    screen.blit(surf, surf_center)
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Player, self).__init__()
            self.surf = pygame.image.load("Jake.anime.png").convert()
            self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
            self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    
    player = Player()
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if presed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5,0)
    
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT
    
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                running = False
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
    
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player.update(pressed_keys)
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
    
    class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Enemy, self).__init__()
            self.surf = pygame.image.load("graham.enemy.png").convert()
            self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
            self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
                center=(
                    random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                    random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
                )
            )
            self.speed = random.randint(5, 20)
    
        def update(self):
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
            if self.rect.right < 0:
                self.kill()
    
    class Cloud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Cloud, self).__init__()
            self.surf = pygame.image.load("cloud for game.png").convert()
            self.surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0), RLEACCEL)
            self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
                center=(
                    random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                    random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
                )
            )
    
        def update(self):
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
            if self.rect.right < 0:
                self.kill()
                
    
    player = Player()
    enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
    clouds = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites.add(player)
    
    running = True
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    
    ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 250)
    ADDCLOUD = pygame.USEREVENT +2
    pygame.time.set_timer(ADDCLOUD, 1000)
    
    player = Player()
    
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                elif event.type == QUIT:
                    running = False
                elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
                    new_enemy = Enemy()
                    enemies.add(new_enemy)
                    all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
                elif event.type ==ADDCLOUD:
                    new_cloud = Cloud()
                    clouds.add(new_cloud)
                    all_sprites.add(new_cloud)
    
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player.update(pressed_keys)
        enemies.update()
        clouds.update()
    
    screen.fill((135, 206, 250))
    
    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
        running = False
```

Comment: Don't know why my imports spaced differently on this

Comment: We can't debug 100s of lines of code for you. Please provide a minimum reproduceable example (which is also a good thing to do for your own debugging!)

Comment: You should add `pygame.display.update()` in all of the `while` loops so the display can actually update

Comment: U should update the display in pygame with pygame.display.update() in your main loop

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple `while running` loops and are not calling `pygame.display.update` at the end to draw everything.  You should have one loop which checks for events, updates everything, and draws everything.

```
while running:
  get_events()
  update()
  draw()
```

move all the code for each thing inside its own function.  Collision checking would be at the end of update().  Also I am not sure why you have indented the from pygame.locals import, that should be left aligned, as should the class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your program. Write 1 application loop only. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage

See also [Python Pygame Introduction](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html) and see the following example for a minimal application loop:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# main application loop
run = True
while run:

    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    window.fill(0)

    # draw the scene   
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (250, 250), 100)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py)</kbd>

See also [Event and application loop](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/documentation/pygame/pygame_event_and_application_loop.html)

---

Complete applicaition:

```py
import pygame
import random

from pygame.locals import (
    RLEACCEL,
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Jake.anime.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5,0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("graham.enemy.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 20)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()

class Cloud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cloud, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("cloud for game.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
            

player = Player()
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
clouds = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 250)
ADDCLOUD = pygame.USEREVENT +2
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDCLOUD, 1000)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:

    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False    
        if event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_enemy = Enemy()
            enemies.add(new_enemy)
            all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
        elif event.type ==ADDCLOUD:
            new_cloud = Cloud()
            clouds.add(new_cloud)
            all_sprites.add(new_cloud)

    # update objects
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    enemies.update()
    clouds.update()

    # clear the display
    screen.fill((135, 206, 250))

    # draw the scene   
    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
        running = False
    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```